# Show Credit Card Type Icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML code - Linked to this JS code which is used to identify the type of credit card

This function uses the `parseCardType` method to return the credit card name by number (visa, mastercard, amex). I would like to see the Fontawesome icon of the card shown within the `ct` span instead of the name. Is there any way to do this?

```js
function updateType(e) {
  var cardType = payform.parseCardType(e.target.value);
  type.innerHTML = cardType || 'invalid';
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ccnumber">Numero della carta</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ccnum" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000" autocomplete="cc-number">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span id="ct" class="input-group-text">
                                            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. What is payForm? Please add relevant CDNs

Comment: Yes, there is. Depending on type put proper icon class on element via JS

Answer (score 0):

Is it Bootstrap? If so, try something like this:

```js
type.innerHTML = `<i class="fa-cc-${cardType}"></i>` || 'invalid';
```